# equals - symmetric contract in java seems to be giving issue

Tags: java, equals

I'm testing the symmetric contract of object Equals method mentioned in the Effective Java 2nd Edition Book.

> Symmetric: For any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) must return
>   true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

Can you explain me - why `list.contains(s)` still returns false in the below code.

```
public final class CaseInsensitiveString {
    private final String s;

    public CaseInsensitiveString(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.s = s;
    }

    // Broken - violates symmetry!
    /*
     * @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
     *  if (o instanceof  CaseInsensitiveString)
     *   return s.equalsIgnoreCase(((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s); 
     *   if (o instanceof String) // One-way  interoperability
     *    return s.equalsIgnoreCase((String) o); return false; 
     *    }
     */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString
                && ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s.equalsIgnoreCase(s);
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CaseInsensitiveString cis = new CaseInsensitiveString("Polish");
        String s = "polish";
        // System.out.println(cis.equals(s));
        // System.out.println(s.equals(cis));
        List<CaseInsensitiveString> list = new ArrayList<CaseInsensitiveString>();
        list.add(cis);
        System.out.println(list.contains(s));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list contains a single instance of `CaseInsensitiveString`. `s` is a **`String`** instance, which cannot be equal to any `CaseInsensitiveString` since `o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString` which appears in the `equals` method will return `false`.

If you test your code with two instances of `CaseInsensitiveString` that are constructed by strings containing the same values in different cases, you'll see that the `contains` call will return `true`:

```
CaseInsensitiveString titleCase = new CaseInsensitiveString("Polish");
CaseInsensitiveString lowerCase = new CaseInsensitiveString("polish"); // Here!
List<CaseInsensitiveString> list = new ArrayList<CaseInsensitiveString>();
list.add(titleCase);
System.out.println(list.contains(lowerCase)); // prints true
```

Comment: Would that be a correct fix if instead of removing `String` comparison from `equals`, it was modified to `CaseInsensitiveString extends String`?

Comment: @SMUsamaShah `java.lang.String` is `final`, you cannot extend it.

Comment: Ok, but it wouldn't have violated symmetry in the first place if it was extendable?

Comment: @SMUsamaShah it probably still would. Consider the following - `s1 = "Hello"; s2 = new CaseInsensitiveString("hello")`. In that case `s1.equals(s2)` would return `false`, but `s2.equals(s1)` would return false.

Answer (score 2):

Because `s` is a `String` so `o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString` will return false.